# Is there any good reason in having a stateless contract?

Tags: solidity

If I understand correctly, then any stateless `contract` can be re-declared as a `library`.

Is there any advantage or benefit in keeping it as a `contract`?

If there is any, then I guess it would be in terms of runtime (i.e., gas cost).

I cannot see any differences in terms of compile-time.

But I'd be happy to get an answer referring to both aspects.

Thank you!!!